# Facebook Social Plugin comment count

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm using facebook connect and facebook social plugin comment ( ). I want to get comment count from current page. How to write it ? Need to use FQL ? If fql,

```
SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE xid= ?
```

what xid should I add? How to get xid from current address ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();

$fbconfig['appid' ]  = "1111111";
$fbconfig['api'   ]  = "2222222";
$fbconfig['secret']  = "3333333";

$xid = 'myCommentBox'; 

include_once "facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid' ],
    'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
    'cookie' => true,
));

$fql = "SELECT count FROM comments_info WHERE app_id = '".$fbconfig['appid' ]."' AND xid = '$xid' ";
$param  =   array(
    'method'    => 'fql.query',
    'query'     => $fql,
    'callback'  => ''
);
$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
print_r( $fqlResult );
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Count FB comment!</title>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=<?=$fbconfig['appid' ]?>&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
   <fb:comments xid="<?=$xid?>" numposts="10" width="600" publish_feed="true"></fb:comments>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Burgi - `<?=` is perfectly fine--it's not a short tag.

Comment: @DavidHarkness PHP calls it short open tag - what do you call it? <?= requires short_open_tag to be true, which isn't the case on (rough guess) 95% of all servers as it's been deprecated for years now.

Comment: @Burgi - You're correct! Been spending too much time in PHP 5.4 land. :) However, `<?=` won't be mistaken for an XML declaration like `<?`, and it only matters if ultra-portability is a concern and you don't have access to multi-file search-and-replace. Also, I doubt that 95% is anywhere near accurate. It's certainly not worthy of a downvote in my book.

Comment: @DavidHarkness I upvoted the answer in fact ;) The reason why I commented in such a negative manner is because I've always been taught that using the long syntax is best practise and imho it's also more readable for frontend devs.

Answer (score 0):

you just neeed to query comments_info by providing your app id, It will return xid and count specific to a particular xid.